# Correct formating and re-use of code blocks

Tags: python, function, variables, xml-parsing

So I had a requirement to build out a script that accessed an API to pull reports from a firewall, below is the hash job I made, for those of you who are fluent in python please be kind, I realize I am probably breaking every rule there is.

So the questions: (the script is available here - https://github.com/Marct27/PAN_reporter)

- I have a limited understanding of functions I have noticed that I am re-using certain parts of the script that I could pass arguments to.

  ```
  #Parse xml and get root key value
  tree = ET.parse(resp)
  root = tree.getroot()
  #From return xml find job id of report
  j=root.find('status')
  jID=j.find('job')
  ```

I would assume that the function would look something like this:

```
        def parseXML(arg1, arg2):
            #Parse xml and get root key value
            tree = ET.parse(resp)
            root = tree.getroot()
            #From return xml find job id of report
            j=root.find(arg1)
            jID=j.find(arg2)
            print 'Job ID :', jID.text
            return jID
```

However when I try to call the function with:

```
parseXML('status','job')
```

I end up with the following error:

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-4-03280b8af912> in <module>()
         62                 time.sleep(5)
         63             #From xml get job status
    ---> 64                 apiPullReport = '/api/?
    type=report&action=get&job-id=%s&key=%s' % (jID.text, apiKey)
         65                 req = urllib2.Request(host+apiPullReport, head)
         66                 resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, context = ctx)

    NameError: name 'jID' is not defined
```

Do I need to declare a global variable that the function would up date or is there another way for the variable to be defined ?

- Should I be looking at using a class (not sure if that is the right term) for something like this? or what would the suggested correct formatting be to make it more "python correct"

Comment: `jID = parseXML('status','job')` first, and then you can use it outside its function.

Comment: ah.. thank you that makes sense now. anything you can suggest I should look in to around the general formating  and structure (not asking you to re-write, just looking for suggestions to read up on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by **coldspeed** for pointing out that the variable required to be returned by the function needs to be defined in order to use it.

> `jID = parseXML('status','job')` first, and then you can use it outside its function. – cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 53 mins ago

Updated the guthub files if anyone wants to review.

Thanks again for the help

Comment: If you want your code to be reviewed, you can ask at [Code Review stack exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, did not know that was a thing :)